# Scrol down by pressing button in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html code:

```
<div class="get-start-area">
    <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="name@company.com">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Get Started">
</div>
```

and this js code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var btnScrollDown = document.querySelector('.submit');
  function scrollDown() {
    var windowCoords = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    (function scroll() {
      if (window.pageYOffset < windowCoords) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 10);
        setTimeout(scroll, 10);
      }
      if (window.pageYOffset > windowCoords) {
        window.scrollTo(0, windowCoords);
      }
    })();
  }
  btnScrollDown.addEventListener('click', scrollDown);
})();
```

After pressing `Get Started` I need to see contact area, but scroll goes just one second and I can see just nearest block of information. So, how can I change the values in the script to increase time of scroll in page?

And this is html of contact section:

```
<section class="footer-contact-area section_padding_100 clearfix" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Heading Text  -->
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h2>Subscribe!</h2>
                        <div class="line-shape"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-text">
                        <p>We`ll send you weekly news to make your app more convinient. Stay tune.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Form Start-->
                    <div class="contact_from">
                        <form action="#" method="post">
                            <!-- Message Input Area Start -->
                            <div class="contact_input_area">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
<!--
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message *" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
-->
                                    <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn">Send Now</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Message Input Area End -->
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

So I can't understand why script doesn't work correctly.

Comment: This seems to work for me, what is the problem you're having?  https://jsfiddle.net/ricardo_reyna/1pjxdugr/24/

Comment: @RicardoReyna how can I increase the time of scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of JS:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 10);
```

to this:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 1);
```

Edit:
Or any number lower than 10 for that matter

Comment: it didn`t help. its just controls the speed of scrolling(

Comment: Isn't that what you are trying to do? Can you edit your question then to make it clearer what exactly you want to accomplish?

Comment: Grgic, I want to increase the time of scroll, I mean I need to go to `contact` area, but in this example I just can scroll to `about` area which is the nearest area in the page